Unexpected Key Value in Spring Boot `@ConfigurationProperties`
I have the following configuration in my Spring Boot application.yml file:
widget-proxy-route:
  /my/**:
    stripPrefix: 1
    targetUri: bbbbbbbbb

And I have a @ConfigurationProperties class to retrieve the widget-proxy-route value as follows:
import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.util.HashMap;

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "widget-proxy-route")
public class RouteProperties extends HashMap<Object, RouteProperties.ProxyRoute> {
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        for(Object key : keySet()) {
            System.out.println("key:" + key + ", ProxyRoute:" + this.get(key));
        }
    }

    @Data
    public static class ProxyRoute {
        private String targetUri;
        private Integer stripPrefix;
    }
}

However, the key value I'm getting is unexpected:

Expected: /my/**
Actual: my

How can I resolve this issue?
Let me know if you'd like me to revise anything! 
I've tried the following approaches, but they didn't work:
widget-proxy-route:
  /my/**:
    stripPrefix: 1
    target: bbbbbbbbb
  "/my/**":
    target: bbbenbbbbb
  \/my\/\*\*':
    target: bbbenbbbbb
  \\/my\\/\\*\\*':
    target: bbbenbbbbb

I attempted to modify the application.yml configuration by adding quotes, escaping forward slashes, and using different combinations of quotes and escapes, but none of them yielded the expected result.

try '[/my/**]' see spring-boot-yaml-configuration-with-url-in-key

Thank you @DirkDeyne , you must be an angel.
